# phpMyAdmin DELETE query only shows Loading... screen

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.1.19-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) PHP/7.0.10
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 241ae00989d1995ffcbbf63d579943635faf9972 $
```

All queries in phpMyAdmin work fine except for any DELETE query, I know they are correct because they work if I run them in a ssh terminal mysql client. But phpMyAdmin only shows "Loading...".

Anyone got a solution for this?

Best Regards
Cisco

Comment: you should share your query from your php so we can help you

Comment: Are you entering your own SQL DELETE statement, clicking the little red 'X' near a row, or using the checkboxes to select several rows to delete at once?

Comment: I have tried all three.. No DELETE works in phpMyAdmin. But it works if I ssh and run sql. :/ @IsaacBennetch

Comment: I have the same problem